# Can anyone provide any details on the model, history and value of my grandfather's watch?

Tags: identification, fashion, gold, engineering

After my grandfather passed away in 2010, a lot of his belongings were split between his daughters. My mother recently gave me a watch that belonged to my grandfather, but I cannot find any details about it online besides the fact that the maker, Eska, is an old watch maker.

The brown leather strap is not the original strap that came with the watch.

Any ideas on the model/history/worth of this watch?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'd say that this is unusual in that the logo on the watch face is all uppercase whereas the logo is usually mixed case (as shown on the back)

Comment: The logo on https://poshmark.com/listing/Vintage-Eska-18kt-gold-watch-mechanical-with-strap-5a8f5b343dabbd290728e1b0 is all uppercase, but in a different type style.

Comment: Here's a [listing](https://www.watchpool24.com/en/30734391/eska-vintage-wristwatch) for a different Eska watch that gives some information about the brand. "Eska is a small but high-quality Swiss watch brand founded in Grenchen (Switzerland) at the beginning of the 20th century. The brand name "Eska" is based on the initials of the founder Sylvan Kocher "eS-Ka". Eska was replaced by the brand "Royce" in the 1960s." There's a [Watch Wiki](https://www.watch-wiki.net/doku.php?id=eska) entry too, although it disagrees on some things. and a [company website](http://eska-watch.com/about)

Comment: The serial number on the back of the case is typically meaningless. [How to lookup a pocket watch](https://pocketwatchdatabase.com/reference/how-to-lookup-a-pocket-watch) describes how to properly open the case in order to determine the manufacturer, and serial number, of the movement inside. Caveat: You might wish to pay a qualified watchmaker to do this for you.